# How to use a calculated field in a subquery (sqlite3)

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have this code that works in **MySQL**

```
CASE
    WHEN e.sex = 'M' THEN ROUND((salary / 30 * absents) + (salary / 30 / 8 * short_hours * 1.5))
    ELSE ROUND((salary / 30 * absents) + (salary / 30 / 5 * short_hours * 1.5))
END AS deductions,

CASE
    WHEN e.sex = 'M' THEN ROUND(salary / 30 / 8 * overtime * 1.5)
    ELSE ROUND(salary / 30 / 5 * overtime * 1.5)
END AS overtime_bonus,

ROUND(salary - (SELECT deductions) + (SELECT overtime_bonus)) AS total_salary,
```

I am trying to make it work in **SQLite** but I get the error `no such column: deductions`

My question is: can I use a calculated field in a subquery in SQLite3?

Comment: No, this does not work in SQLite.

Comment: Include a complete query, not a fragment of one. You might need to use a subquery, CTE, view, or generated column, though.

Comment: You also might want to find a different example than code that shows how your company systematically pays women less money for the same hours, that's kind of not the best example one could come up with these days.